# Why do some Arduino-compatible boards provide a crystal for the CH340?

Tags: arduino, serial, crystal, ttl

I have an uno-shaped Arduino compatible which uses the CH340(G) serial to ttl converter chip and it is connected to an external crystal.

I also have nano shaped compatible which uses the CH340(C) serial to ttl converter chip which has no external crystal although it does have pads ready to accept one.

My question is: Why does the one board's serial chip require a crystal and the other not? is it because they use different CH340 variants? And also why is there the need for the space for an external crystal on the smaller board?

Comment: *Why does the uno serial chip require a crystal and the nano one not?* The difference in how the CH340 gets its clock signal has no relation to an Arduino uno vs nano. It has to do with the circuit chosen for that particular model. When configured properly also an uno board can be made without a crystal and a nano with a crystal.

Comment: This question is off topic as it requires *guessing* the intent of the designer.  You may be able to learn something from the CH340 data sheet, but presumably both boards you have work.

Comment: "is it because they use different CH340 variants?" - Yes. From a datasheet: "CH340C, CH340E and CH340B have built-in crystal" Price may be a factor because I'd imagine the ones without built-in crystal to be cheaper.

Comment: Thanks JimmyB, i had a look here - https://www.mpja.com/download/35227cpdata.pdf and the CH340C is indeed not connected whereas CH340G requires a Xtal. Chris Straton, im not sure what you mean by my question being off topic. Yes the boards work but that doesnt help my curiosity...

Comment: @user2105725 - "why did they do x" questions are usually off topic, because as previously explained they require *guessing the intent of the designer*.  The SE system is about facts, not guesses.  The infrequent exceptions are situations where there is a clear independently-documented fact which is overwhelmingly likely to be the case.   The apparent difference in CH340 versions could almost be an example - but there's still the unanswerable except as a guess of why different versions were used.

Answer (score 10):

This is because some varieties of CH340 (namely, CH340B, CH340C and CH340E) have a built-in oscillator and cannot be connected to a quartz. Compare the pinouts of G and C chips for example:

[image]

Since the two chips are identical except for the oscillator part, it makes sense to design a single PCB compatible with both ICs, and simply leave the quartz circuit unpopulated when the CH340C is used.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me to understand why my board is different from original schematics.